# Strange Quark Matter

Tags: particle-physics, quarks

I am watching a video on neutron stars.  The video is discussing the collision of 2 neutron (quark) stars and the ejection of strangelets.  That if one of these strangelets comes into contact with regular matter it will convert it to strange matter.    Why is this repeated so often?  Is there any truth to the strange matter changing other matter into strange matter?

If so, why doesn't particle accelerators that have made strange quarks and strange mesons and such convert?

Also if strange matter is so stable, why do particles with strange quarks decay? Such as Kaons, Strange D Meson, etc.

Comment: There are [several types](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strange_matter). Strange quarks in isolation are (weakly) unstable to lighter ones, being heavier, and likewise inside individual hadrons. If you bind them in big nuclei or stars, the binding energy might offset their heavier mass price, and... Can you focus your question?

Comment: Given that we currently believe that many heavier elements on Earth are due to neutron star merger ejecta, stable strangelets would also likely have shown up here. So the evidence for the mergers is a pretty good piece of evidence against risky strangelets.

Comment: It's odd that the "dangerous strangelet" keeps getting brought up on respectable sites like PBS and others.   The other problem I have with the strangelet question is this:  If a strangelet hits Mercury.  The collision might have enough energy to change some of Mercury's down quarks to strange quarks. In order to change the entire planet, where is this energy coming from?   Something has to provide it?

Comment: The science vetting of PBS is distinctly subpar. Again, *only* condensed (hypernuclear) stars, never plain matter, could be endangered by strangelets.